# How to calculate the dimension of the Lie algebra associated with the complex Lorentz group? Calculate the generators associated with the Lie algebra

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

How can I demonstrate that the set of matrices, $U$, that are consistent with Equation 1 form a group?
\begin{align}
\tag{1}
U^\dagger 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0
\\
0&-1&0&0
\\
0&0&-1&0
\\
0&0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
U
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0
\\
0&-1&0&0
\\
0&0&-1&0
\\
0&0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
where the $\dagger$ indicates conjugate transpose.

I guess I have to show the 3 main properties of a group:(But, how?)

1. that the associative property  is valid
2. that there exists an  inverse $\text{inv}(U)*U=1$
3. and identity element. $U*I=U$

In the case it is a group. Is it a Lie group? Which is the dimension of the associated Lie algebra? I also have to find the generators of the Lie algebra associated with that group.

Note that the we are working in the complex space $\Bbb C$ in 4 dimensions.This is not the classical Lorentz group of all the books because it is not in $\Bbb R^4$.

So far I have found that this group of matrices is called complex Lorentz group.(Is it a subgroup of the pseudo-unitary group (3,1). In this case we are working with a signature diag(-1,1,1,1).Physics convention.

And the last question is if there is any relation between this Lie algebra with:

1. Casimir operators
2. Cartan subalgebra

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3617394/proof-that-a-set-of-matrices-form-a-group-is-it-a-lie-group-calculate-the-gene). Again, yes, it is a Lie group. For the dimension of the Lie algebra see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308594/lie-algebra-of-the-lorentz-group-so1-3-uparrow?rq=1).

Comment: Yes I know,but how do you prove it?

Comment: What do you want to prove? That it is a Lie group? Every matrix group is a Lie group.  Please don't post questions twice.

Comment: Noo,I mean how do you prove that the dimension of the associated lie Algebra is 16.Sorry for my english.

Comment: Why do you think the dimension is $16$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard method of proving this is a Lie group is by constructing the homomorphism $\Phi:GL_n(\mathbb{C}) \to Herm(n)$ given by

$$
\Phi(A) \;\; =\;\; AMA^\dagger.
$$

Here the set $Herm(n)$ is the $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices which is a vector space of real dimension $n^2$, and of course $\dim GL_n(\mathbb{C}) = 2n^2$.  **We want to prove that $\Phi$ is a smooth equivariant function.  This will show that $\Phi$ is of constant rank.  If this occurs then the inverse image $\Phi^{-1}(M)$ will be equivalent to the Lorentz group in question and the theory of Lie groups shows us that this is a Lie subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ of dimension $2n^2 - \text{rank}(\Phi)$.**

Let $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ act on itself by left multiplication and let it act on the set of Hermitian matrices as $A\cdot H = AHA^\dagger$.  Then the function $\Phi$ is equivariant since:

$$
\Phi(AB) \;\; =\;\; ABM(AB)^\dagger \;\; =\;\; ABMB^\dagger A^\dagger \;\; =\;\; A\cdot \Phi(B).
$$

Equivariant maps are of constant rank, hence all we need to do is find the rank of the map $\Phi$.  We have freedom to choose the base point, hence we can compute $\text{rank }d\Phi_I$ at the identity.  Observe that if we let $\gamma:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ be a curve where $\gamma(0) = I$ and $\gamma'(0) = B$ then we find that

\begin{eqnarray*}
d\Phi_I(B) & = & \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right |_{t=0}\Phi(\gamma(t)) \\
& = & \left . \frac{d}{dt} \right |_{t=0} \gamma(t)M\gamma(t)^\dagger \\
& = & MB^\dagger + BM \;\; =\;\; BM + (BM)^\dagger
\end{eqnarray*}

hence showing that $d\Phi_I \subseteq Herm(n)$.  To show that it is surjective, we can acknowledge that $T_IGL_n(\mathbb{C}) = M_n(\mathbb{C})$, so if we let $P$ be any Hermitian matrix, then $\frac{1}{2}PM \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ will get sent to $P$:

$$
d\Phi_I\left (\frac{1}{2}PM\right ) \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{2}(PM)M + \left (\frac{1}{2}PMM\right)^\dagger \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{2}P + \frac{1}{2}P \;\; =\;\; P
$$

hence $d\Phi_I$ has full rank which is $n^2$.  This proves the complex Lorentz group is a Lie group of dimension $2n^2 - n^2 = n^2$.  Hence, in the case the $n=4$ this would 16-dimensional.

**Generators**

In general, we can at best expect to find *local generators* for a Lie group, and these can be discerned from the Lie algebra.  If $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of a Lie group $G$, then letting $A_1, \ldots, A_k$ be a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$, then we can find local generators of the form $\exp(tA_i)$, thus the issue in discerning the generators comes down to finding the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{l}_n(\mathbb{C})$ of $\Lambda_n(\mathbb{C})$ and picking a basis.  Note that we can uncover the Lie algebra structure by looking at the equation above for $d\Phi_I(B) = BM + MB^\dagger$.  We know this must be zero given the equation $AMA^\dagger = M$.  What we find here is:

$$
BM + MB^\dagger =0 \;\; \Longrightarrow \;\; B^\dagger = -MBM,
$$

which if you multiply this out essentially gives you the equation:
$$
\left [ \begin{array}{cc}
\alpha^* & \overline{v^T} \\
\overline{u^T} & \tilde{B}^\dagger \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
-\alpha & u \\
v & - \tilde{B} \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

where we find $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}, \; u,v \in \mathbb{C}^3$, and $\tilde{B} \in M_3(\mathbb{C})$.  The relationships $\alpha^* = - \alpha$ tells us that $\alpha \in i\mathbb{R}$.  Also that $u = \overline{v^T}$ restricts the structure of the matrix to just one vector in $\mathbb{C}^3$.  Lastly that $\tilde{B}^\dagger = - \tilde{B}$ is that $\tilde{B} \in \mathfrak{u}(3)$ the Lie algebra of $3\times 3$ skew-Hermitian matrices.  This tells us that

$$
\mathfrak{l}_n(\mathbb{C}) \;\; \cong\;\; i\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{C}^{n-1} \oplus   \mathfrak{u}(n-1)
$$

You can verify this Lie algebra is 16-dimensional.  My suggestion is to pick a basis $\{A_1, \ldots, A_{16}\}$ of this vector space and compute $\exp(tA_k)$ for each value of $k$.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Do you know how can i find the generators?

Comment: @minipablorufadorPablogamer See edits.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer to next the question, "Is $\text{SU}(1,3)$ a group?"*

By $\text{U} (1, 3)$ I denote the pseudo-unitary group of complex matrices $U$ satisfying the condition $U\,g\,U^\dagger = g$, where $g$ is a diagonal matrix with elements $g_{11} = 1$   and $g_{kk} = -1$ for $2 \leq k \leq 4$. Explicitly,
$$
g = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0
\\
0&-1&0&0
\\
0&0&-1&0
\\
0&0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Paraphrasing from [1],

> A group is a non-empty set together with a binary operation on the set  that combines any two elements  of  to form an element of the set  such that the  group axioms, are satisfied.

**(a)**
We must show that the set $\text{U}(1,3)$, which is a non-empty set, together with the binary operation matrix multiplication on $\text{U}(1,3)$ combines any two elements $U_1$ and $U_2$ of $\text{U}(1,3)$ to form an element of $\text{U}(1,3)$, denoted $U_1\,U_2$.

To begin with observe that the product $U_1\,U_2$ is an element of  $\text{U}(1,3)$:
\begin{align}
\left(U_1\,U_2\right)^\dagger g
\left(U_1\,U_2\right)
&=
\left(U_2^\dagger\, U_1^\dagger\right) 
g\left(U_1\,U_2\right)
&&
(\text{rule of matrix multiplication})
\\
&=
U_2^\dagger\, U_1^\dagger 
\,g\,
 U_1\,U_2 
&&
(\text{rule of matrix multiplication})
\\
&=
U_2^\dagger\,  
g
\,
U_2 
&&
(U_1~\text{satisfies OP's Eq. 1})
\\
&=
g
&&
(U_2~\text{satisfies OP's Eq. 1})
\end{align}

**(b) First group axiom**
Next, we must show that for $U_1$, $U_2$, and $U_3$ in $\text{U}(1,3)$ one has   $U_1 \left(U_2 \,U_3\right)=
\left(U_1 \,U_2 \right)U_3$. Well, each of these three matrices are square matrices. Thus, the products
$(U_1 \,U_2 )\,U_3$ and $U_1 (U_2 \,U_3)$ are defined; and one has the associative property $(U_1 \,U_2 )\,U_3=U_1 (U_2 \,U_3)$.

**(c) Second group axiom**
Next, we must show that there exists an element $e$ in  $\text{U}(1,3)$ such that, for every $U$ in $\text{U}(1,3)$, one has $e \, U = U$   and $U\, e = U $. Well, note that
$e = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ works. I can show that
$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ is in $\text{U}(1,3)$ by writing
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}^\dagger g
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0 \\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}g\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\\
&=
g.
\end{align}
Further, one can see by matrix multiplication that
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \, U = U\quad\text{and}\quad U\, \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} = U .$$

**(d) Third group axiom**
We must show that for each $U_1$ in $\text{U}(1,3)$, there exists an element $U_2$ in $\text{U}(1,3)$ such that $U_1  \,  U_2  = e$  and $U_2\, U_1 =e$. Well, from the OP's Equation 1, we get that
\begin{align}
\det\left(
U_1^\dagger 
\,g\,U_1
\right)
&= 
\det(g) 
\\
\det 
\left(U_1^\dagger \right)
\det
(g)\,\det(U_1)
&= 
\det(g)
\\
\det 
\left(U_1^\dagger \right)
\det(U_1)
&=
1.
\end{align}
So,
$$
\tag{2}
\left(\det 
U_1 \right)^\dagger
\det{U_1}
=
1.$$
Assuming falsely that $\det U_1 = 0$, gives $\left(\det 
U_1 \right)^\dagger
\det{U_1}
=0$. This leads to a contradiction
with Equation 2. So, truly $\det U_1 \neq 0$. Since the determinant of $ U_1  $  is not equal to zero, therefore exists an element $U_2$ such that $U_2\,U_1 = e$ and $U_1\,U_2 = e$. By $U_1^{-1}$ I denote the inverse of $U_1$ . Further, I show that the inverse is in $\text{O}(1,3)$. Now, since   $g 
 =
U\,g 
\,
U^\dagger  $, therefore
\begin{align}
\left(U^{-1}\right)\,g \left(U^\dagger  \right)^{-1}
& =
U^{-1}\,U\,g 
\,
\left(U^\dagger  \right)\left(U^\dagger  \right)^{-1}
\\
\left(U^{-1}\right)\,g \left(U^\dagger  \right)^{-1}
& =
g 
\\
\left(U^{-1}\right)\,g \left(U^{-1}  \right)^\dagger
& =
g 
\end{align}
In the last line, we see that $\left(U^{-1}\right)
$ satisfies the OP's Equation 1. Thus,
$\left(U^{-1}\right)
\in \text{U}(1,3)$.

Q.E.D

**Bibliography**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group

[2]

Answer (score 0):

*Answer to next the question, "Is $\text{SU}(1,3)$ a Lie group?"*

There appears to be many ways and several conditions to determine the matter (cf, [1]). That said, I can wrap my head around the following definition from [2]:

> Definition: [Matrix Lie group]A *matrix Lie group*, which is also called a *linear Lie group*, is a **closed subgroup** of GL$(n;\mathbb{C})$.

I have showed in a accompanying answer to this question that $\text{U}(1,3)$ is a group.  Further, $\text{U}(1,3)\subset  \text{GL}(4, \mathbb{C} ).$ What remains to show is that the limit of a sequence of psuedo-unitary matrices is itself a psuedo-unitary matrix.

**Proof**

Let us take the  sequence $\left(A_m\right)$   of matrices all of which are in U(1,3). I start with a proof by induction [3], and finish by taking a limit.

*The base case:*
I start with
\begin{align}
 A_1 = \prod_{j=1}^1 U_{j}.
\end{align}
By construction $U_1 \in  \text{U}(1,3) $.

*The inductive step:* I show that if the statement holds for any given case $m =k$, then it  also hold for the next case $m = k + 1$. Observe. Now,
\begin{align}
\left(A_{k+1}\right)  \,g\,
\left(A_k\right)^\dagger
&=
\left(A_k\,U_{k+1} \right) \,g\,
\left(A_k\,U_{k+1}\right)^\dagger
&&
(\text{by construction})
\\
&=
\left(A_k\,U_{k+1}  \right) \,g\,
\left(U_{k+1}\right)^\dagger
\left(A_k \right)^\dagger
&&
(\text{rule of matrix multiplication})
\\
&=
 A_k\,U_{k+1}    \,g\,
 U_{k+1} ^\dagger\,
 A_k ^\dagger
&&
(\text{rule of matrix multiplication})
\\
&=
 A_k  \,g\,
 A_k ^\dagger
&&
(U_{k+1}~\text{satisfies}~U_{k+1}\,g\,U_{k+1}^\dagger = g)
\\
&=
g
&&
( A_k~\text{satisfies}~ A_k\,g\, A_k^\dagger = g)
\end{align}
By induction, I conclude that a finite sequence of pseudo-unitary matrices is pseudo-unitary.

Finally, given $A = \lim_{m\to\infty}\left(A_m\right)$, we have that $A \in  \text{U}(1,3) $. This is true because the relation $A \,g\,A ^\dagger = g$ is preserved under taking limits.

Q.E.D.

**Bibliography**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-subgroup_theorem

[2] Hall, "*Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations*," pp, 3-4,6, 2000.

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction

Answer (score 0):

*Answer to the questions, "What is is the dimension of the associated Lie algebra?"*

I begin with a definition from [1]

> Definition.  Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a matrix Lie group. The **Lie algebra of $\mathcal{G}$**, denoted $\mathfrak{g}$, is the set of all matrices $X$ such that $e^{tX}$ is in  $\mathcal{G}$ for all real numbers $t$.

Adapting from [1], I reason as follows. Recall that a matrix $U$ is pseudo unitary if, and only if, $u\,g\,U^\dagger = g$. Thus, $e^{tX}$ is psuedo unitary if, and only if,
$$
e^{tX}\,g\,\left(e^{tX}\right)^\dagger = g$$
for all real numbers $t$. Or, alternatively, if, and only if,
$$
g\,\left(e^{tX}\right)^\dagger = e^{-tX}\,g \tag{1}$$
for all real numbers $t$. Since Eq. 1 holds for all $t$, then by differentiating at $t=0$, we see that
$$
g\,X ^\dagger = -X \,g  $$
is the necessary condition for Eq. 1 to hold.

Thus, the Lie algebra of $U(1,3)$, which is denoted by $\mathfrak{u}(1,3)$, is the space of all $n\times n $ complex matrices $X$ such that
$ 
g\,X ^\dagger = -X \,g \tag{2}  $.

The dimension of each and every $n\times n $ invertible   complex matrices is $2\,n^2$. Yet, as given by Eq. 2, each and every $n\times n $ matrix in   $\mathfrak{u}(1,3)$ has $n^2$ constraints imposed upon them. Thus, the dimension of
$\mathfrak{u}(1,3)$ is $n^2$ (i.e., $2\,n^2-n^2$ ).

**Bibliography**

[1] Hall, "*Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations*," pp. 39-40, 2000.